# my code get stuck in infinte loop after pressing yes button in dialog builder in function onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

my code get stuck in infinte loop after pressing yes button in dialog builder in function onRequestPermissionsResult .Again and again builder came out when i press yes.Also after pressing no ,my app exit but when i open it again it shows the dialog builder

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case 0: {
                boolean anyPermissionDenied = false;
                boolean neverAskAgainSelected = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        anyPermissionDenied = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!anyPermissionDenied)
                {
                    getConfigFromServer();
                } else {
                    String message = "";
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ||
                            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))  {

                        requestPermission();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "You have to give all permission to continue";
                    }
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
                            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                        requestPermission();

                                        }
                                    });

                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
            break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }


    }
```

code for request permission

```
    void requestPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
        } else {

            getConfigFromServer();
            //navigateToNextActivity();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and its having loop so have edited your code you it will help you.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

String[] MY_PERMISSIONS={
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
};
ArrayList<Integer> deniedPermissionPosition=new ArrayList<>();
String[] AGAINPERMISSIONS;
boolean firstTime=true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestPermission(firstTime);
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0: {
            boolean anyPermissionDenied = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    anyPermissionDenied = true;
                    firstTime=false;
                    deniedPermissionPosition.add(i);
                }
            }
            if (!anyPermissionDenied)
            {
                getConfigFromServer();
            } else {
                Log.e("DEBUG","Permission Denied");
                String message = "";
                    message = "You have to give all permission to continue";
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
                    alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    requestPermission(firstTime);
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                    alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }


}
void requestPermission(boolean firstTime) {
    if(firstTime){

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, MY_PERMISSIONS, 0);
        } else {

            getConfigFromServer();
        }
    }else {
        AGAINPERMISSIONS=new String[deniedPermissionPosition.size()];
        for (int permissions = 0; permissions < deniedPermissionPosition.size(); permissions++) {
            AGAINPERMISSIONS[permissions]=MY_PERMISSIONS[deniedPermissionPosition.get(permissions)];
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, AGAINPERMISSIONS, 0);
    }
}

private void getConfigFromServer() {
    Log.e("DEBUG","Method call");
}
}
```

If you have any question you can post in comment.

Comment: the app get crash when i enter never ask again

Comment: mine is not crashing in any situation. Please add error log here.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: ops.hungerbox.com.hungerboxops, PID: 11348 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3

Answer (score 0):

it popup again after clicking no because  you havent set any thing so in onRequestPermissionsResult ,your if-condition anyPermissionDenied happen , but for `alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()`  i think its better if you post your requestPermission mehtod or atleast you should debug it to see whats happening

Comment: actually i cant see any problem with your AlertDialog